# Mongodb TTL expires documents early

Tags: python, mongodb, ttl

I am trying insert a document into a Mongo database and have it automatically expire itself after a predetermine time. So far, my document get inserted but always get deleted from the database from 0 - 60 seconds even though I set the 'expireAfterSeconds' to much longer.  I know mongodb  deletes expired documents about every 60 seconds so it seems the 'expredAfterSeconds' variable is not working.

I followed the documentation here:
[Mongodb TTL Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)

Here is my test code that should expire (delete) the document after 3 minutes (but it does it under a minute):

```
import pymongo
import datetime

mongo_con = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 27017)
mongo_db = mongo_con.Mongo_database
mongo_col = mongo_db.my_TTL_collection

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()

mongo_col.ensure_index("date", expireAfterSeconds=3*60)                     

mongo_col.insert({'_id': 'login_session', "date": timestamp, "session": "test session"})
```

Does anybody have any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Note that ensure_index is now deprecated in pymongo and mongodb with mongodb >3., it will fall back to insert_index

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your problems come from using naive timestamps in your local timezone. The [FAQ of pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#what-is-the-correct-way-to-handle-time-zones-with-pymongo) has an entry which includes a warning not to use `datetime.datetime.now()`.
Using `utcnow`, the `ttl`-setting works as expected:

```
import pymongo
import datetime

mongo_con = pymongo.Connection('localhost', 27017)
mongo_db = mongo_con.Mongo_database
mongo_col = mongo_db.my_TTL_collection

timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

mongo_col.ensure_index("date", expireAfterSeconds=3*60)                     

mongo_col.insert({'_id': 'session', "date": timestamp, "session": "test session"})
mongo_col.insert({'_id': 'utc_session', "date": utc_timestamp, "session": "test session"})
# the utc_session will be deleted after around 3 minutes, 
# the other depending on your timezone
```

Answer (score 5):

For Pymongo 3 this is the updated Syntax.

```
mongo_collection.create_index("date", expireAfterSeconds=3*60)
```